# Can I create a trigger in mysql schema in phpmyadming

Tags: mysql, triggers

When I ran the same query in different databases, it works successfully. But in mysql schem it gives error:

`#trigger can not be created on system table`

My query is:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `invite` AFTER INSERT ON `Invite_page`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    Insert into userpost(userid,url,title,preview,sentiment,time) values(NEW.userid,NEW.url,NEW.title,NEW.preview,NEW.sentiment,NEW.time);
    Insert into urlcontent(userid,url,title,preview,sentiment,time) values(NEW.userid,NEW.url,NEW.title,NEW.preview,NEW.sentiment,NEW.time);
END
//
delimiter ;
```

If I can't, then how can I solve this instead?

UPDATE:

actual error:

`#1465 - Triggers can not be created on system tables`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `invite` AFTER INSERT ON `Invite_page`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    Insert into userpost(userid,url,title,preview,sentiment,time) values(NEW.userid,NEW.url,NEW.title,NEW.preview,NEW.sentiment,NEW.time);
    Insert into urlcontent(userid,url,title,preview,sentiment,time) values(NEW.userid,NEW.url,NEW.title,NEW.preview,NEW.sentiment,NEW.time);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: so the `Invite_page` is a system table? are you sure??

Comment: @zzalani: I have created that table manually. it's not system table

Comment: @Programming_crazy have you selected the database?

Comment: well no if you have tables in mysql schema you cant do nothing you actually need to create new database first and then create your tables views prods etc. there ..

Answer (score 1):

Under the "*Restrictions for triggers*" section in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html you can read:

> Triggers are not permitted on tables in the mysql database.

BTW, are you using the `mysql` schema to store data? This is (usually) a very bad idea and probably you need to rethink your setup.

Comment: my all table are in `mysql` schema. SO i need to create trigger in it. is it not possible?

Comment: No, it is not possible. You need to create a new schema and put your info in there, and leave the `mysql` schema alone.

Comment: why would you have tables in mysql_schema?

Comment: from day one when I started using phpmyadmin. I used to work withing that schema only, i really could not believe this.